# Python: curve fit looks scrambled

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve to some data but the resulting curve looks like a scrambled mess. I don't know whether or not the coefficients are accurate. With this sample data set it prints something like a triangle and with my original data set it looks even worse. It's mostly tutorial. I tried removing the sympy code from an alternate tutorial, but doing so accomplished nothing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

x = [0.0009425070688029959,
0.0009398496240601303,
0.0018779342723004293,
0.004694835680751241,
0.0009425070688029959,
0.004734848484848552,
0.0018993352326685255,
0.0009460737937558928]
y = [0.0028301886792453904,
0.003762935089369628,
0.001881467544684814,
0.0009433962264150743,
0.0028301886792453904,
0.0019029495718363059,
0.0038058991436727804,
0.0018939393939393534]
"""
Plot your data
"""
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro',label="Original Data")

"""
brutal force to avoid errors
"""    
x = np.array(x, dtype=float) #transform your data in a numpy array of floats 
y = np.array(y, dtype=float) #so the curve_fit can work

"""
create a function to fit with your data. a, b, c and d are the coefficients
that curve_fit will calculate for you. 
In this part you need to guess and/or use mathematical knowledge to find
a function that resembles your data
"""
def func(x, b, c, d):
  return b * x * x + c * x + d

"""
make the curve_fit
"""
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

"""
The result is:
popt[0] = a , popt[1] = b, popt[2] = c and popt[3] = d of the function,
so f(x) = popt[0]*x**3 + popt[1]*x**2 + popt[2]*x + popt[3].
"""
print("b = " + str(popt[0]) + "  c = " + str(popt[1]) + "  d = " + str(popt[2]))

"""t
Use sympy to generate the latex sintax of the function
"""
xs = sym.Symbol('\lambda')    
tex = sym.latex(func(xs,*popt)).replace('$', '')
plt.title(r'$f(\lambda)= %s$' %(tex),fontsize=16)

"""
Print the coefficients and plot the funcion.
"""

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label="Fitted Curve") #same as line above \/
#plt.plot(x, popt[0]*x**3 + popt[1]*x**2 + popt[2]*x + popt[3], label="Fitted Curve") 

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: The plotted curve from the data above.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Matplotlib will only draw lines between the few points in your original data (in the x and y arrays) and in the order they are defined. There are only 3 unique x values (plus some noise) which is why you see what looks like a triangle.

The fix is to create a new array with evenly spread, and ordered, x values across the range you're interested in. You can do that with the [linspace function in numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

For example, try this for your second plot command:

```py
x_eval = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)

plt.plot(x_eval, func(x_eval, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
```

`x_eval` above is a list of 100 evenly spread values between the minimum and maximum x value in your original data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to sort on `xdata`.

Try inserting this:

`x,y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))`

Such that

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

x = [0.0009425070688029959,
0.0009398496240601303,
0.0018779342723004293,
0.004694835680751241,
0.0009425070688029959,
0.004734848484848552,
0.0018993352326685255,
0.0009460737937558928]
y = [0.0028301886792453904,
0.003762935089369628,
0.001881467544684814,
0.0009433962264150743,
0.0028301886792453904,
0.0019029495718363059,
0.0038058991436727804,
0.0018939393939393534]
"""
Plot your data
"""
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro',label="Original Data")

"""
brutal force to avoid errors
"""    

x,y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))

x = np.array(x, dtype=float) #transform your data in a numpy array of floats 
y = np.array(y, dtype=float) #so the curve_fit can work

"""
create a function to fit with your data. a, b, c and d are the coefficients
that curve_fit will calculate for you. 
In this part you need to guess and/or use mathematical knowledge to find
a function that resembles your data
"""
def func(x, b, c, d):
  return b * x * x + c * x + d

"""
make the curve_fit
"""
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

"""
The result is:
popt[0] = a , popt[1] = b, popt[2] = c and popt[3] = d of the function,
so f(x) = popt[0]*x**3 + popt[1]*x**2 + popt[2]*x + popt[3].
"""
print("b = " + str(popt[0]) + "  c = " + str(popt[1]) + "  d = " + str(popt[2]))

"""t
Use sympy to generate the latex sintax of the function
"""
xs = sym.Symbol('\lambda')    
tex = sym.latex(func(xs,*popt)).replace('$', '')
plt.title(r'$f(\lambda)= %s$' %(tex),fontsize=16)

"""
Print the coefficients and plot the funcion.
"""

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label="Fitted Curve") #same as line above \/
#plt.plot(x, popt[0]*x**3 + popt[1]*x**2 + popt[2]*x + popt[3], label="Fitted Curve") 

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

The plotted curve from the data above.
```

Comment: This results in connected line segments rather than a curve.

Comment: Depending on the application, that can be what one wants. It is true to the connected data points.  Your question tile noted that the curve looks scrambled, so I sorted it out.  Looks like what you wanted was an interpolation using the estimated formula.